# Make a table span in multiple pages in Latex

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table that takes up a full page, but I want it to start on a page that already has some text and then continue onto the next page. It is a long table and I really need it to be split. Here is the code of my table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
\\[-1.5ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.5ex] 
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Outcome}} \\ 
\cline{2-5} 
\\[-1.5ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\ 
\\[-1.5ex] & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & (t value) & (\operatorname{Pr}(>|t|))\\ 
\hline \\[-1.5ex] 
 GDAXI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000821& 0.000000& 1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.037) & (0.035) & (0.047) & (0.032) \\ 
& & & & \\ 
 GDAXI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000003 & 0.048846 & 0.961042 \\ 
  %& (0.039) & (0.036) & (0.049) & (0.033) \\ 
 & & & & \\ 
 GDAXI.alpha1 & 0.050730& 0.012555 & 4.040571& 0.000053 \\ 
 % & (0.029) & (0.027) & (0.037) & (0.025) \\ 
& & & & \\ 
 GDAXI.beta1 & 0.900100 & 0.032728& 27.502568 & 0.000000 \\ 
 % & (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.055) & (0.037) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FCHI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000813 & 0.000000 & 1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.036) & (0.033) & (0.045) & (0.030) \\ 
& & & & \\ 
 FCHI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000004 & 0.031265 & 0.975058 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.035) & (0.024) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FCHI.alpha1 & 0.051329 & 0.016720 & 3.069932 & 0.002141\\ 
 % & (0.031) & (0.028) & (0.039) & (0.026) \\ 
& & & & \\ 
 FCHI.beta1 &0.900178 & 0.039227& 22.948028 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.055) & (0.037) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FTAS.mu & 0.000000 &  0.000818 & 0.000000 & 1.000000\\ 
  %& (0.034) & (0.032) & (0.043) & (0.029) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FTAS.omega & 0.000000 &  0.000003  & 0.077804 & 0.937984 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.036) & (0.024) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FTAS.alpha1 & 0.051058 & 0.011707 &  4.361314 & 0.000013 \\ 
  %& (0.042) & (0.039) & (0.053) & (0.036) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 FTAS.beta1& 0.900120 & 0.028077 & 32.058802 & 0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.038) & (0.035) & (0.048) & (0.032) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 SSMI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000686 & 0.000000 &1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.054) & (0.037) \\ 
& & & & \\ 
 SSMI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000002 & 0.049328 & 0.960658 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.036) & (0.024) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 SSMI.alpha1 & 0.051473 &0.007339 & 7.013881&  0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.045) & (0.042) & (0.057) & (0.038) \\ 
 & & & & \\ 
 SSMI.beta1 &0.900169 & 0.017583 & 51.196838 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.037) & (0.034) & (0.046) & (0.031) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
 dcca1 & 0.023229 & 0.003674 & 6.322145 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.0004) & (0.0004) & (0.001) & (0.0004) \\ 
  & & & & \\ 
dccb1 & 0.957464 & 0.006762 & 141.590704 & 0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.0004) & (0.0004) & (0.001) & (0.0004) \\ 
  %& & & & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.5ex] 
Information Criteria &  & &  &  \\
  & & & & \\ 
Akaike        & -24.205 &  &  &  \\ 
Bayes  & -24.055 &  & &  \\ 
Shibata    & -24.207 &  &  &  \\ 
Hannan-Quinn & -24.147 &  &  & \vspace{2mm} \\
Elapsed time:  & 4.92738 &  &  &  \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.5ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Can anyone help me please I really need this to go on with my thesis is blocking me to go ahead. Thank in advance!

Comment: You should use a `longtable` **instead** of a table+tabular. Everything inside a `table` environment is a floating, and it's limited to one page.

Comment: Do you mean to delete the table and tabular and just use begin longtable?

Comment: I'm trying but maybe I'm doing something wrong. Can you please modify my code from above in the way you think is correct! Thank you I would really appreciate it if you help me

Comment: Why this question have the `r` tag?

Comment: It is a mistake sorry !

Comment: Please, first extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. Table contain errors.

Comment: Please can you help me  I'm quite new in latex and this is a table R studio created using the stargazer package and now I really need this table to be split as is leaving me  
with spaces and empty pages and I do not know how to solve this problem.  I try to see videos and different tutorials but until now I'm for sure missing something .

Comment: You should almost never put yourself in a situation where you need to fill out such a large table with data. If you’re writing a scientific report, the full data set should never be included in the report, only the statistical conclusions. The full data set can then be included in an auxiliary file for your colleagues to review if they need to (which they almost certainly don’t).

Comment: I need it for my thesis and my professor asked me to include the output as it is from R studio. Thank you for you suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Longtable in `tabularray`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
[
long,
caption={Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices},
label={xxxxx}
]
{
colspec={lcccc},
cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c},
hline{1,Z}={1}{-}{0.05em},
hline{1,Z}={2}{-}{0.05em},
hline{2}={2-Z}{0.05em},
hline{3,21}={0.05em},
}
                     & Outcome    &             &            &                             \\
                     & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & (t value)  & ($\operatorname{Pr}(>|t|$)) \\
GDAXI.mu             & 0.000000   & 0.000821    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
GDAXI.omega          & 0.000000   & 0.000003    & 0.048846   & 0.961042                    \\
GDAXI.alpha1         & 0.050730   & 0.012555    & 4.040571   & 0.000053                    \\
GDAXI.beta1          & 0.900100   & 0.032728    & 27.502568  & 0.000000                    \\
FCHI.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000813    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
FCHI.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000004    & 0.031265   & 0.975058                    \\
FCHI.alpha1          & 0.051329   & 0.016720    & 3.069932   & 0.002141                    \\
FCHI.beta1           & 0.900178   & 0.039227    & 22.948028  & 0.000000                    \\
FTAS.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000818    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
FTAS.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000003    & 0.077804   & 0.937984                    \\
FTAS.alpha1          & 0.051058   & 0.011707    & 4.361314   & 0.000013                    \\
FTAS.beta1           & 0.900120   & 0.028077    & 32.058802  & 0.000000                    \\
SSMI.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000686    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
SSMI.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000002    & 0.049328   & 0.960658                    \\
SSMI.alpha1          & 0.051473   & 0.007339    & 7.013881   & 0.000000                    \\
SSMI.beta1           & 0.900169   & 0.017583    & 51.196838  & 0.000000                    \\
dcca1                & 0.023229   & 0.003674    & 6.322145   & 0.000000                    \\
dccb1                & 0.957464   & 0.006762    & 141.590704 & 0.000000                    \\
Information Criteria &            &             &            &                             \\
Akaike               & -24.205    &             &            &                             \\
Bayes                & -24.055    &             &            &                             \\
Shibata              & -24.207    &             &            &                             \\
Hannan-Quinn         & -24.147    &             &            &                             \\
Elapsed time:        & 4.92738    &             &            &                             \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Float table with `tabularray`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices}
\label{xxxxx}
\centering
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={lcccc},
cell{1}{2}={c=4}{c},
hline{1,Z}={1}{-}{0.05em},
hline{1,Z}={2}{-}{0.05em},
hline{2}={2-Z}{0.05em},
hline{3,21}={0.05em},
}
                     & Outcome    &             &            &                             \\
                     & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & (t value)  & ($\operatorname{Pr}(>|t|$)) \\
GDAXI.mu             & 0.000000   & 0.000821    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
GDAXI.omega          & 0.000000   & 0.000003    & 0.048846   & 0.961042                    \\
GDAXI.alpha1         & 0.050730   & 0.012555    & 4.040571   & 0.000053                    \\
GDAXI.beta1          & 0.900100   & 0.032728    & 27.502568  & 0.000000                    \\
FCHI.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000813    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
FCHI.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000004    & 0.031265   & 0.975058                    \\
FCHI.alpha1          & 0.051329   & 0.016720    & 3.069932   & 0.002141                    \\
FCHI.beta1           & 0.900178   & 0.039227    & 22.948028  & 0.000000                    \\
FTAS.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000818    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
FTAS.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000003    & 0.077804   & 0.937984                    \\
FTAS.alpha1          & 0.051058   & 0.011707    & 4.361314   & 0.000013                    \\
FTAS.beta1           & 0.900120   & 0.028077    & 32.058802  & 0.000000                    \\
SSMI.mu              & 0.000000   & 0.000686    & 0.000000   & 1.000000                    \\
SSMI.omega           & 0.000000   & 0.000002    & 0.049328   & 0.960658                    \\
SSMI.alpha1          & 0.051473   & 0.007339    & 7.013881   & 0.000000                    \\
SSMI.beta1           & 0.900169   & 0.017583    & 51.196838  & 0.000000                    \\
dcca1                & 0.023229   & 0.003674    & 6.322145   & 0.000000                    \\
dccb1                & 0.957464   & 0.006762    & 141.590704 & 0.000000                    \\
Information Criteria &            &             &            &                             \\
Akaike               & -24.205    &             &            &                             \\
Bayes                & -24.055    &             &            &                             \\
Shibata              & -24.207    &             &            &                             \\
Hannan-Quinn         & -24.147    &             &            &                             \\
Elapsed time:        & 4.92738    &             &            &                             \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Regression Results for the period from 2006 to 2008}
\label{xxxxxxxx}
\centering
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={Q[l,m]*{4}{Q[c,m]}},
cell{1,2,Z}{2}={c=4}{c},
cell{even[4-37]}{1}={r=2}{},
hline{1,Z}={1}{-}{0.05em},
hline{1,Z}={2}{-}{0.05em},
hline{2}={2-Z}{0.05em},
hline{even[4-37]}={2-Z}{0.05em},
hline{4,38,Y}={0.05em},
row{1}={font=\itshape},
cell{1}{Z}={font=\itshape},
rowsep=1pt
}
                                  & Dependent variable:                              &                  &                  &                  \\
                                  & y                                                &                  &                  &                  \\
                                  & (GDAXI)                                          & (FCHI)           & (FTAS)           & (SSMI)           \\
GDAXI.l1                          & $-$0.355$^{***}$                                 & 0.084$^{**}$     & 0.118$^{**}$     & 0.038            \\
                                  & (0.037)                                          & (0.035)          & (0.047)          & (0.032)          \\
FCHI.l1                           & 0.076$^{*}$                                      & $-$0.099$^{***}$ & 0.130$^{***}$    & $-$0.111$^{***}$ \\
                                  & (0.039)                                          & (0.036)          & (0.049)          & (0.033)          \\
FTAS.l1                           & 0.201$^{***}$                                    & $-$0.001         & $-$0.099$^{***}$ & 0.037            \\
                                  & (0.029)                                          & (0.027)          & (0.037)          & (0.025)          \\
SSMI.l1                           & 0.219$^{***}$                                    & $-$0.053         & $-$0.124$^{**}$  & $-$0.173$^{***}$ \\
                                  & (0.043)                                          & (0.040)          & (0.055)          & (0.037)          \\
GDAXI.l2                          & $-$0.245$^{***}$                                 & 0.007            & 0.004            & 0.075$^{**}$     \\
                                  & (0.036)                                          & (0.033)          & (0.045)          & (0.030)          \\
FCHI.l2                           & $-$0.038                                         & $-$0.142$^{***}$ & 0.047            & $-$0.065$^{***}$ \\
                                  & (0.028)                                          & (0.026)          & (0.035)          & (0.024)          \\
FTAS.l2                           & 0.312$^{***}$                                    & 0.100$^{***}$    & $-$0.111$^{***}$ & 0.634$^{***}$    \\
                                  & (0.031)                                          & (0.028)          & (0.039)          & (0.026)          \\
SSMI.l2                           & 0.144$^{***}$                                    & $-$0.032         & $-$0.041         & $-$0.143$^{***}$ \\
                                  & (0.043)                                          & (0.040)          & (0.055)          & (0.037)          \\
GDAXI.l3                          & $-$0.096$^{***}$                                 & 0.618$^{***}$    & 0.076$^{*}$      & 0.182$^{***}$    \\
                                  & (0.034)                                          & (0.032)          & (0.043)          & (0.029)          \\
FCHI.l3                           & 0.041                                            & $-$0.139$^{***}$ & $-$0.032         & 0.028            \\
                                  & (0.028)                                          & (0.026)          & (0.036)          & (0.024)          \\
FTAS.l3                           & 0.565$^{***}$                                    & 0.063            & $-$0.067         & 0.236$^{***}$    \\
                                  & (0.042)                                          & (0.039)          & (0.053)          & (0.036)          \\
SSMI.l3                           & 0.097$^{**}$                                     & $-$0.082$^{**}$  & $-$0.064         & $-$0.035         \\
                                  & (0.038)                                          & (0.035)          & (0.048)          & (0.032)          \\
GDAXI.l4                          & $-$0.120$^{***}$                                 & 0.052            & $-$0.037         & 0.013            \\
                                  & (0.043)                                          & (0.040)          & (0.054)          & (0.037)          \\
FCHI.l4                           & 0.017                                            & $-$0.037         & 0.084$^{**}$     & 0.023            \\
                                  & (0.028)                                          & (0.026)          & (0.036)          & (0.024)          \\
FTAS.l4                           & 0.175$^{***}$                                    & 0.065            & 0.055            & 0.123$^{***}$    \\
                                  & (0.045)                                          & (0.042)          & (0.057)          & (0.038)          \\
SSMI.l4                           & 0.002                                            & 0.300$^{***}$    & $-$0.150$^{***}$ & $-$0.059$^{*}$   \\
                                  & (0.037)                                          & (0.034)          & (0.046)          & (0.031)          \\
const                             & 0.0004                                           & $-$0.0005        & $-$0.0005        & $-$0.0001        \\
                                  & (0.0004)                                         & (0.0004)         & (0.001)          & (0.0004)         \\
Observations                      & 739                                              & 739              & 739              & 739              \\
R$^{2}$                           & 0.460                                            & 0.582            & 0.093            & 0.548            \\
Adjusted R$^{2}$                  & 0.448                                            & 0.573            & 0.073            & 0.538            \\
{Residual Std. Error\\(df = 722)} & 0.012                                            & 0.011            & 0.015            & 0.010            \\
{F Statistic\\(df = 16; 722)}     & 38.403$^{***}$                                   & 62.938$^{***}$   & 4.627$^{***}$    & 54.680$^{***}$   \\
Note:                             & $^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01 &                  &                  &                  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much really, I do not know how to thank you for your time and help. May I ask you something I try your code but when I compline before the table I get this error  "Z¿0Z Z¿0Z Z"

Comment: `tabularray` is new package. I suggest you use TeX Live 2022 or Overleaf with 2022.

Comment: Thank you so much  again I find the solution I upgrade the version of TeX Live

(On Overleaf)

Menu -> TeX Live Version -> 2022 and now is working perfectly. Thank you again you have no idea how much you helped me.

Comment: @Clara can you please give a look at another table I posted above in my answer here I'm also having problems with this one. This is the last one I swear, I really struggling with these two tables for days.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have update it.

Comment: thanks..........

Comment: @user366566 The new table is on the below of this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

With use of the `tabularray` package.  Your code fragment I extend with

- preamble, where are load `geometry` and  `tabularray` packages. To the later are added libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`,
- in table are considered commented table rows where are numbers in parenthesis,
- for numbers are used `si` columns
- for horizontal lines are used rules from `booktabs`

After this completing and changing your table can still fit in one page in `table` float:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=25mm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip,
            font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}%
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {5}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices}
\label{tab:results?}
\sisetup{table-format=3.6,
         input-open-uncertainty=,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         table-align-text-after=false,
         table-align-text-before=false
        }
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l *{4}{X[c,si]} @{}},
                 row{1}   = {font=\itshape},
                 row{1,2} = {guard},
                 row{3-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
             row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
             }
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=4]{c}  Outcome 
            &           &           &           &               \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
            &(Estimate) &(Std.error)&($t$ value)& $(\Pr(>|t|))$ \\
    \midrule
GDAXI.mu    & 0.000000  & 0.000821  & 0.000000  & 1.000000      \\
            & (0.037)   & (0.035)   & (0.047)   & (0.032)   \\
GDAXI.omega & 0.000000  & 0.000003  & 0.048846  & 0.961042      \\
            & (0.039)   & (0.036)   & (0.049)   & (0.033)   \\
GDAXI.alpha1& 0.050730  & 0.012555  & 4.040571  & 0.000053      \\
            & (0.029)   & (0.027)   & (0.037)   & (0.025)   \\
GDAXI.beta1 & 0.900100  & 0.032728  & 27.502568 & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.043)   & (0.040)   & (0.055)   & (0.037)   \\
FCHI.mu     & 0.000000  & 0.000813  & 0.000000  & 1.000000      \\
            & (0.036)   & (0.033)   & (0.045)   & (0.030)   \\
FCHI.omega  & 0.000000  & 0.000004  & 0.031265  & 0.975058      \\
            & (0.028)   & (0.026)   & (0.035)   & (0.024)   \\
FCHI.alpha1 & 0.051329  & 0.016720  & 3.069932  & 0.002141      \\
            & (0.031)   & (0.028)   & (0.039)   & (0.026)   \\
FCHI.beta1  & 0.900178  & 0.039227  & 22.948028 & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.043)   & (0.040)   & (0.055)   & (0.037)   \\
FTAS.mu     & 0.000000  &  0.000818 & 0.000000  & 1.000000      \\
            & (0.034)   & (0.032)   & (0.043)   & (0.029)   \\
FTAS.omega  & 0.000000  &  0.000003 & 0.077804  & 0.937984      \\
            & (0.028)   & (0.026)   & (0.036)   & (0.024)   \\
FTAS.alpha1 & 0.051058  & 0.011707  &  4.361314 & 0.000013      \\
            & (0.042)   & (0.039)   & (0.053)   & (0.036)   \\
FTAS.beta1  & 0.900120  & 0.028077  & 32.058802 & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.038)   & (0.035)   & (0.048)   & (0.032)   \\
SSMI.mu     & 0.000000  & 0.000686  & 0.000000  & 1.000000      \\
            & (0.043)   & (0.040)   & (0.054)   & (0.037)   \\
SSMI.omega  & 0.000000  & 0.000002  & 0.049328  & 0.960658      \\
            & (0.028)   & (0.026)   & (0.036)   & (0.024)   \\
SSMI.alpha1 & 0.051473  & 0.007339  & 7.013881  & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.045)   & (0.042)   & (0.057)   & (0.038)   \\
SSMI.beta1  & 0.900169  & 0.017583  & 51.196838 & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.037)   & (0.034)   & (0.046)   & (0.031)   \\
dcca1       & 0.023229  & 0.003674  & 6.322145  & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.0004)  & (0.0004)  & (0.001)   & (0.0004)  \\
dccb1       & 0.957464  & 0.006762  &141.590704 & 0.000000      \\
            & (0.0004)  & (0.0004)  & (0.001)   & (0.0004) \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=2]{l}    Information Criteria:
            &           &           &           &               \\[1ex]
Akaike      & -24.205   &           &           &               \\
Bayes       & -24.055   &           &           &               \\
Shibata     & -24.207   &           &           &               \\
Hannan-Quinn 
            & -24.147   &           &           &               \\
Elapsed time:  
            & 4.92738   &           &           &               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thank you so much really!

Comment: @user366566, instead of saying "thank you>" you can up-vote answers which you like :-) by clicking on up-triangle at left top side of answer. The solution which best fulfill your expectation you can accept (by clicking on check mark) and with this inform people, that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the `table`/`tabular` setup to a `longtable` setup, while also giving the table a more open and inviting "look", I suggest you follow, at a minimum, the following five steps:

1. Execute

   ```
   \usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
   ```

   in the preamble.
2. Replace the code chunk

   ```
   \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
   \caption{Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices} 
   \label{} 
   \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lcccc} 
   \\[-1.5ex]\hline 
   \hline \\[-1.5ex] 
   & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Outcome}} \\ 
   \cline{2-5} 
   \\[-1.5ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\ 
   \\[-1.5ex] & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & (t value) & (\operatorname{Pr}(>|t|))\\ 
   \hline \\[-1.5ex]
   ```

   with

   ```
   \begin{longtable}{@{} l cccc @{}}

   %% headers and footers

   \caption{Results of the DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices} 
   \label{tab_dccgarch} \\ 
   \toprule
   & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\textit{Outcome}} \\ 
   \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
   & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & ($t$-value) & ($\mathrm{Pr}>|t|$)\\ 
   \midrule
   \endfirsthead

   \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued} \\[0.5ex} 
   \toprule
   & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\textit{Outcome}} \\ 
   \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
   & (Estimate) & (Std.error) & ($t$-value) & ($\mathrm{Pr}>|t|$)\\ 
   \midrule
   \endhead

   \midrule
   \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(Cont'd on following page)}\\
   \endfoot

   \bottomrule
   \endlastfoot
   ```
3. Replace

   ```
   \hline \\[-1.5ex] 
   Information Criteria &  & &  &  \\
     & & & & \\
   ```

   with

   ```
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Information Criteria} \\
   ```
4. Get rid of, or just comment out, all

   ```
    & & & & \\
   ```

   lines.
5. Replace

   ```
   \hline 
   \hline \\[-1.5ex] 
   \end{tabular} 
   \end{table}
   ```

   with

   ```
   \end{longtable}
   ```

---

To make the table more attractive, I'd also *round* all numbers to three decimal digits. This may be accomplished easily with the help of the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%% column type for automatic rounding to three digits:
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l T{-2.3} T{1.3} T{3.3} T{1.3} @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption{Results of DCC-GARCH model for stock market indices} 
\label{tab_dccgarch} \\ 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Outcome} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5} 
& {Coeff.} & {Std err} & {$t$-value} & {$\mathrm{Pr}>|t|$} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued} \\[0.5ex]
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\textit{Outcome}} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5} 
& {Coeff.} & {Std err} & {$t$-value} & {$\mathrm{Pr}>|t|$} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(Cont'd on following page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table

 GDAXI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000821& 0.000000& 1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.037) & (0.035) & (0.047) & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace
 GDAXI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000003 & 0.048846 & 0.961042 \\ 
  %& (0.039) & (0.036) & (0.049) & (0.033) \\ 
\addlinespace
 GDAXI.alpha1 & 0.050730& 0.012555 & 4.040571& 0.000053 \\ 
 % & (0.029) & (0.027) & (0.037) & (0.025) \\ 
\addlinespace
 GDAXI.beta1 & 0.900100 & 0.032728& 27.502568 & 0.000000 \\ 
 % & (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.055) & (0.037) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FCHI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000813 & 0.000000 & 1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.036) & (0.033) & (0.045) & (0.030) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FCHI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000004 & 0.031265 & 0.975058 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.035) & (0.024) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FCHI.alpha1 & 0.051329 & 0.016720 & 3.069932 & 0.002141\\ 
 % & (0.031) & (0.028) & (0.039) & (0.026) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FCHI.beta1 &0.900178 & 0.039227& 22.948028 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.055) & (0.037) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FTAS.mu & 0.000000 &  0.000818 & 0.000000 & 1.000000\\ 
  %& (0.034) & (0.032) & (0.043) & (0.029) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FTAS.omega & 0.000000 &  0.000003  & 0.077804 & 0.937984 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.036) & (0.024) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FTAS.alpha1 & 0.051058 & 0.011707 &  4.361314 & 0.000013 \\ 
  %& (0.042) & (0.039) & (0.053) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace
 FTAS.beta1& 0.900120 & 0.028077 & 32.058802 & 0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.038) & (0.035) & (0.048) & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace
 SSMI.mu & 0.000000 & 0.000686 & 0.000000 &1.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.043) & (0.040) & (0.054) & (0.037) \\ 
\addlinespace
 SSMI.omega & 0.000000 & 0.000002 & 0.049328 & 0.960658 \\ 
 % & (0.028) & (0.026) & (0.036) & (0.024) \\ 
\addlinespace
 SSMI.alpha1 & 0.051473 &0.007339 & 7.013881&  0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.045) & (0.042) & (0.057) & (0.038) \\ 
\addlinespace
 SSMI.beta1 &0.900169 & 0.017583 & 51.196838 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.037) & (0.034) & (0.046) & (0.031) \\ 
\addlinespace
 dcca1 & 0.023229 & 0.003674 & 6.322145 & 0.000000 \\ 
  %& (0.0004) & (0.0004) & (0.001) & (0.0004) \\ 
\addlinespace
 dccb1 & 0.957464 & 0.006762 & 141.590704 & 0.000000\\ 
  %& (0.0004) & (0.0004) & (0.001) & (0.0004) \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Information Criteria} \\
Akaike        & -24.205 &  &  &  \\ 
Bayes         & -24.055 &  &  &  \\ 
Shibata       & -24.207 &  &  &  \\ 
Hannan-Quinn  & -24.147 &  &  & \\[2mm]
Elapsed time: & 4.92738 &  &  &  \\ 

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```